# Apostrophe issues

Tags: grammaticality

I am doubting what would be best (or would be correct) when writing the following title:

1.- A programme to improve teachers' quality

2.- A programme to improve teachers quality

Is there actually any difference?

Many thanks in advance,

EM.

Comment: See [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about avoiding the problem by writing "quality of teachers." Or, better to my mind, "quality of teaching" (this removes the criticism or "blame" from the teachers and puts it on the process).

Comment: Agree. It's the teaching that's got to be improved, not the quality of the person. Also  (esp. if it's a heading and you want a short version): a programme to improve teaching quality.

Comment: Or just 'to improve teaching'?

Comment: Great! I definetely prefer this perspective. Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert per se, but if you want to be grammatically correct, - teachers' - is how'd you use the apostrophe in that sentence. That said, you also need to know your audience. Going with the example of your sentence, if you are selling a computer program to a board of individuals representing teachers, or a group of some kind, it's likely irrelevant. If it's irrelevant, than you want to go with the cleanest visual appearance. Even words/sentences have aesthetic value when you're selling something.

For what it's worth. Hope that helps.

Comment: I don’t think it’s “irrelevant” whether you use correct English or not. The apostrophe is there for a reason. Not using it indicates one of two things: laziness, or ignorance.

Comment: I agree with the fact that the aesthetic aspect of words does matter in many cases, if not all. 
Since this time the title is for an article, I think I should prioritise grammar correctness. 

Thanks a lot for your contribution, Mark!